RuntimeWarning with numpy.sqrt when trying to calculate distance between vectors
I got the following Warning:
/tmp/ipykernel_4554/4230604056.py:37: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt   return np.sqrt((X**2).sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] - 2 * X.dot(self.X_train.T) + (self.X_train**2).sum(axis=1))
related to the method of computing distances between two set of vectors:
def compute_distances(self, X):
    return np.sqrt((X**2).sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] - 2 * X.dot(self.X_train.T) + (self.X_train**2).sum(axis=1))

Returned expression is nothing but matrix, whose (i, j) element is just distance w.r.t. to l2 metric between vectors X[i] and self.X_train[j] therefore can't be negative. So what can be problem then?

The warning is likely due to numerical instability. There could be small negative values produced due to floating-point arithmetic imprecision.
These tiny negative values occur when the computed distance is extremely close to zero.
You may want to try dividing the whole operation in various steps. For example, in the following code, I set X_train and X_test to be very close, i.e., X_test = X_train + 1e-10, which would make distances be very small and the output highlights this problem:
import numpy as np

def compute_distances_stable(X_train: np.ndarray, X: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    X_squared_norm = np.sum(X**2, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    X_train_squared_norm = np.sum(X_train**2, axis=1)
    cross_term = 2 * X.dot(X_train.T)
    distances = np.maximum(X_squared_norm - cross_term + X_train_squared_norm, 0)
    return np.sqrt(distances)

def compute_distances_original(X_train: np.ndarray, X: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.sqrt((X**2).sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] - 2 * X.dot(X_train.T) + (X_train**2).sum(axis=1))

# Create example data
np.random.seed(42)
X_train = np.random.randn(4, 3)  # Training vectors
X_test = X_train + 1e-10  # Test vectors

print("Original Method Distances:")
original_distances = compute_distances_original(X_train, X_test)
print(original_distances)

print("\nStable Method Distances:")
stable_distances = compute_distances_stable(X_train, X_test)
print(stable_distances)

Output:
Original Method Distances:
[[0.00000000e+00 1.35651570e+00 1.80004086e+00 1.16083025e+00]
 [1.35651570e+00 2.10734243e-08 1.03039748e+00 1.03320782e+00]
 [1.80004086e+00 1.03039748e+00 2.10734243e-08 1.60924227e+00]
 [1.16083025e+00 1.03320782e+00 1.60924227e+00            nan]]

Stable Method Distances:
[[0.00000000e+00 1.35651570e+00 1.80004086e+00 1.16083025e+00]
 [1.35651570e+00 2.10734243e-08 1.03039748e+00 1.03320782e+00]
 [1.80004086e+00 1.03039748e+00 2.10734243e-08 1.60924227e+00]
 [1.16083025e+00 1.03320782e+00 1.60924227e+00 0.00000000e+00]]
/tmp/ipykernel_24540/934535663.py:19: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  return np.sqrt((X**2).sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis] - 2 * X.dot(X_train.T) + (X_train**2).sum(axis=1))

Note the nan value in the lower right position of the matrix output by your original method, which is replaced by a 0 by the stable method.
The key here is to use np.maximum() which clips any tiny negative values to zero before taking the square root.
